# "An a hundred millilitre bottle"

Tags: articles, slang, numbers, dialect

After searching online for some time, I still haven't found anything quite like my question (which probably indicates that I'm wrong). Even though English is my native language I just found out that I'm prone to saying the following sentence in this way (spoken not written language):

> I drank from **an a** hundred millilitre bottle.

Even though the "an a" is probably redundant, it still feels correct to say it like this (of course we may substitute the "an a" for "a one"). Am I the only native speaker making this mistake or is this some kind of regional nuance / slang that I'm unaware of (I'm from South West England)?

Comment: You do hear it but it's slangy.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey interesting. When written down it still looks horrible. Just out of curiosity do you know if this is only a British thing?

Comment: Would you say "an a pint mug" as well? Surely the capacity is used attributively.

Comment: @KateBunting no not really hahaha. must be slang then. I think it has to do more with the hundred than the unit itself.

Comment: I wouldn't dignify this doubled-up article usage with the label "slang". It's evidence of "linguistic incompetence".

Comment: @FumbleFingers What part of the UK are you from? If enough people say it it's not linguistic incompetence anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and tbf I've never actually written it down. It's more of a it comes out when talking quickly.

Comment: @David - it's a bit like saying 'would of', 'could of', should of' etc, I suppose, which make me shudder. Lots of people say and write those, and they are definitely very wrong in standard English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ok makes sense. That's just because the 've and of sound so similar.

Comment: Sure, *if enough people say it*, it must be more or less "valid". But you're asked *Am I the only native speaker making this "mistake"?*, which strongly implies you don't claim to have heard many (any?) other native Anglophones saying it. I don't think it's remotely comparable to people saying *I would **of** done that*, which is primarily a *spelling* issue anyway (we can't distinguish abbreviated ***have = 've*** from ***of***). I'm from UK SE too, btw.

Comment: Duplicate on ELU: ["A hundred" treated as one word in speech (extra indefinite article)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/601838/191178)

Comment: @Laurel thank you for finding that article. It was a very interesting read. But I beg to differ on three accounts: 1) I was asking in the context of the UK 2) emphasis on spoken language and relatively rapid speech 3) more specific case (the examples mentioned don't sound quite right to me).

Comment: How does "a an" come out when talking *quickly*? When I try to bend it like that, I have to slow down. Anyway, searching on site:.uk, I see a lot of 100 ml bottles, *most of which* are not for drinking from but rather for stuff like perfume or shampoo. It is also the size for rule on the limit for bottles carried in hand luggage (unless that's changed).

Comment: @Lambie it's "an a" not "a an". I kind of fuse both articles together to get "ana".

Comment: Whoops, but even so, very odd and tonguetwisting. The thing is this: What exactly is in those 100 ml bottles you drink out of? You really say this frequently? If I were saying it (that's a big if). I'd just say: "uh" 100 litre bottle.

Comment: @Lambie you're correct. The fusion sounds more like from "unuh" 100 mL bottle. I don't drink from it. The original context was a 100 mL Erlenmeyer flask. I myself don't know many 100 mL bottles for drinking.

Comment: @Lambie Not that frequently. And if I'm talking a bit slower I would probably say "from a one 100 mL bottle". I think it's more of a "it suits the rhythm of the sentence if you're talking fast".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a grammar standpoint, it's wrong, plain and simple. The reason it is being so heavily debated is because we can see the reasoning behind why someone could think it's correct.

You're probably thinking that:

1. We say "a hundred" to mean "*one* hundred", so they are technically interchangeable.
2. The measurement of "100 ml" forms part of the name of the bottle, is, therefore, a compound noun, and compound nouns can be preceded by an article.

But, the indefinite article cannot form part of a countable compound noun. Logically, a common noun is countable and you denote the number either with a numeral (eg "one bottle") *or* a determiner, such as an article (eg "a bottle", "that bottle", or "my bottle).

There's nothing wrong with saying "a hundred" instead of "one hundred" if the context allows it, but just as we adjust the form of the indefinite article (*a/an*) to fit the context, there's no argument for saying we can say it with an article that sounds unnatural. Saying "*the a hundred ml bottle*" or "*an a hundred ml bottle*" sounds unnatural *because it is*, just as saying "*a apple*" instead of "*an apple*" sounds weird (and is incorrect).

The exception to the 'rule' of not having an article as part of a compound noun would be *proper nouns*. I can think of a few bands with articles in their names such as "*The Beatles*" or "*A Flock of Seagulls*". You'll notice that, in common use, English speakers modify names like these to avoid the awkward, unnatural use of two articles. They might drop the article and say "*I'm a Beatles fan*", instead of "I am a 'The Beatles' fan"; or say "*I'm a fan of A Flock of Seagulls*" and not "*I'm a A Flock of Seagulls fan*". So, there's plenty of precedent for adjusting the way we say something if the article makes it unnatural.

Comment: +1 and I'd go further about the band names and say native speakers omit articles at the beginning of band names rather than duplicating them: "*I'm a Beatles fan*", and "*I'm a Flock of Seagulls fan*".

Comment: @gotube I don't make the mistake with band names. It sounds horrible. When I originally posted my question I already knew that it wasn't completely acceptable given that it looks horrible in its written form. I was wondering whether it was more of a grey area and hence acceptable in spoken language or at least in South West England.